# Cannot find parent: org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j for project: null:log4j-core:jar:null for project null:log4j-core:jar:null

Tags: java, maven, logging, null, log4j

I am trying to upgrade the log4j version of my application, but when I run `mvn clean install` to get the .ear file I always have the same error.

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Parent: null:log4j-core:jar:null of project: unknown:log4j-core has wrong packaging: jar. Must be 'pom'. for project unknown:log4j-core
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.assembleLineage(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1403)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildInternal(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:823)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.project.artifact.MavenMetadataSource.retrieveRelocatedProject(MavenMetadataSource.java:163)
    ... 25 more
```

Analyzing the error message, it looks like I'm pointing the wrong .pom file somewhere, but the dependencies look fine for me.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

[Path that I want to reach running `mvn clean install`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJpow.png)

Here is also the entire `pom.xml` of my .ear application and the path to the .pom file that is wrongly referenced by my application.

`


Server
com.client.bi
1.0-SNAPSHOT

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>ClientCRM-ejb-jar</artifactId>
<packaging>ejb</packaging>
<name>ClientCRM-ejb-jar</name>
<properties>
    <rootFolder>..${file.separator}..</rootFolder>
    <resourceFolder>src/main/resources</resourceFolder>
    <powermock.version>1.5.5</powermock.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbossws-jboss423</artifactId>
        <version>${jbossws-version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.ws.native</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbossws-native-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jbossws-version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.ws.native</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbossws-native-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>${jbossws-version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.j2ee</groupId>
        <artifactId>j2ee</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
        <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1.ga</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jsqlparser</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsqlparser</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.2.a</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0.10</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1.ga</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jboss</groupId>
        <artifactId>concurrent</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jboss</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbossmq-client</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jboss</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-common-client</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jboss</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-system-client</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jboss</groupId>
        <artifactId>jnp-client</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmock-junit3</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>   
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>${powermock.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
        <version>${powermock.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>ClientCRM-ejb-jar</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <ejbVersion>3.0</ejbVersion>
                <archive>
                    <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <filters>
        <filter>src/main/resources/properties/${targetEnvironment}.properties</filter>
    </filters>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
            </includes>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${resourceFolder}</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${resourceFolder}</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.sql</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
</build>
```

`

[Path that I am reaching with `mvn clean install` (wrong path)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReM0H.png)

Also, the `log4j-2.3.2.pom` in the image above has the `301 Moved Permanently` code on the content.

Could someone help me with this? I'm here to give more information if you need.

**Last update:**

When I get rid of the `repository` folder inside `$HOME/.m2` as recommended, I had the following error message:

```
Project ID: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin
POM Location: C:\Users\<My User>\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-clean-plugin\2.2\maven-clean-plugin-2.2.pom

Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin at C:\Users\<My User>\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-clean-plugin\2.2\maven-clean-plugin-2.2.pom
```

Comment: Personally I am removing Log4J from all my projects as fast as possible.

Comment: Actually, If I could I would haha.

Comment: Please, don't post the errors as images, but as text. Anyway you have a _"Not a version 4.0.0 POM..."_ root cause, that suggests an error occurred while downloading `org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j`. Now you have a corrupted local copy, just delete it.

Comment: I did it already and tried to run `mvn clean install` again, but it didn't work at all.

Comment: I updated the post with the new error message that I'm having after include log4j and log4j-api artifacts in `pom.xml`

Comment: What are those first `<dependency>` references? And why do they specify different versions (2.3 and 2.3.2)?

Comment: Looking at that image, it appears that you're using some sort of proxy server / local repository to store your artifacts. Is that true?

Comment: I recommend that you delete your local maven repository (`$HOME/.m2/repository` on Linux), then run your build again. If it fails, paste all of the output in your questions -- not a screenshot.

Comment: Just to answer you, @Parsifal. The dependencies above log4j-core are recommended dependencies in order to migrate from slf4j (with log4j 1.x) to apache log4j 2.x (at least this is what I understood from this link: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html). And yes, I use some sort of proxy to get the dependencies, but I realized that the proxy is no longer avaliable and, honestly, I don't know what to do now.
I updated the post to you verify it. Thanks for all the support :)

Comment: OK, starting with the repository server: normally you configure that in [settings.xml](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.4/maven-settings/settings.html), although you can also put `<repository>` entries in your POM. Once you correct this, you'll need to delete your repository directory again to get rid of any corrupted files.

Comment: I suspect that the "Not a v4.0.0 POM" is caused by the repository server. I'm betting that if you look at it you'll see HTML rather than an actual POM. There's no other reason for the POM for a Maven plugin to be corrupted.

Comment: I suspect that you're also using a very old version of Maven: the [maven-clean-plugin](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-clean-plugin) is currently at version 3.1.0, and version 2.2 was released in 2007. If you're using Java8, you should download the latest version.

Comment: The same comment applies to the Log4J version: the latest version, for Java 8, is [2.17.1](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core). Version 2.3.2 appears to be a release that fixes the Log4Shell vulnerability for people who are using Java 1.5 (or maybe 1.6). The Log4J project has made a lot of changes since then (some for the better, some for the worse).

Comment: You got all right, @Parsifal. I'm using JDK 6 and Maven 2.2.1 to compile the project, so the latest version of Apache Log4J for these artifacts is 2.3.2. Actually, I already solved my problem. That error message is quite self explanatory. Basically, I was missing the correct version of parent artifact for log4j-api and log4j-core (parent artifact: log4j). I realized that 2.3 actually was not the latest version for log4j artifact but, as you suggested above, 2.3.2. I will post the solution with more details later. Thanks for all the support, guys :)